# How to avoid less compilator to calculate

Tags: css, less

I've a little trouble and don't find the anwser in the doc.
So this is what less compilator is doing :

> input : 5px - 2px
>
> ouput : 3px
>
> or
>
> input : 10% - 2px
>
> ouput : 8%

I've a case that I want to keep this calcul

```
width: calc(100% - 10px);
```

the output, after compilation, is

```
width: calc(90%);
```

How can I avoid this behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes `"` and a leading `~`:

`width: calc(~"100% - 10px");`

This will tell the compiler to use the string as is.